# Twitter oAuth Token MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, meteor

I have an app that automates some twitter functions such as auto tweet when a user unfollows etc, but to do so I need to access user Token inside my MongoDB using accounts-twitter for the login system, if I query a random user `Meteor.users.findOne().services.twitter` I get this:

```
Object {id: "2436681638", lang: "es", profile_image_url: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/458630414601424896/lxD3ThZt_normal.jpeg", profile_image_url_https: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/458630414601424896/lxD3ThZt_normal.jpeg", screenName: "mr_obtuso"}
```

I can't see the oAuth token stored using accounts-twitter... Without token I am unable to schedule tweets for each user... Is that because `accounts-twitter` itself doesn't store Token or I am doing something wrong?

Basically I need to store access token in order to schedule tweets using Meteor and account-twitter (or any other Twitter service capable of login a user)